# How to program midi-driver software?

Tags: windows, usb, driver, midi

I am creating my own midi-instrument and would like to know how to create a PC driver program for this instrument. Does anyone have any pointers or resources I could look at to help me complete this task?

All i have found so far is
1) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt187811(v=vs.85).aspx  --> USB drivers

Answer (score 2):

Just make your device conform to the [USB MIDI device class specification](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/), and you do not need to write any driver for the PC.

Comment: What if I have a very old commercial device that has not been supported in a long time, can I reverse engineer it?  I also found a [Linux driver](https://github.com/sgorpi/midex8), but wonder can this be easily ported to work with Windows 11.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Driver samples for Windows 10](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples). The [Sample KMDF Function Driver for OSR USB-FX2](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/usb/kmdf_fx2) might be closer to what you need, if you want to write a USB device driver.